# Слайдер с запрещенными диапазонами

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Как создать слайдер, в котором некоторые диапазоны значений будут отключены?

Я вообщем то могу заставить ползунок перескакивать на ближайшую разрешенную позицию, но хорошо бы динамически выделять запрещенные области другим цветом.

Comment: Покажите хоть картинку, как вы это видите

Answer (score 1):

Подкрасить недопустимые значения, вы можете в HTML разметке с помощью CSS. Для накладывания ограничения на некоторые значения `value` вам необходимо при инициализации объекта подписаться на событие `slide` и в нем проверять какое значение в данный момент выбрано и если оно не подходит под ваши условия, скидывать значение на нужное вам. 
Если все-таки необходимо сделать это динамически, лучше написать отдельный метод генерирующий нужную вам разметку для слайдера и подставляющий к запрещенным цифрам нужный вам css класс.